# Use JavaScript to return items that match from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Whats the best way to show all items with matching values using JSON?

So if I have this sample JSON:

```
{
    "AllQuotes": [{
        "Quote": "Life is Bad",
            "Attributes": {
            "StatedYear": 1999,
                "smart": true,
                "inspiring": false
        }
    }, {
        "Quote": "Life is Good",
            "Attributes": {
            "StatedYear": 1972,
                "smart": false,
                "inspiring": true
        }
    }, {
        "Quote": "Let's Party",
            "Attributes": {
            "StatedYear": 1999,
                "smart": false,
                "inspiring": true
        }
    }, {
        "Quote": "All is a Game",
            "Attributes": {
            "StatedYear": 1952,
                "smart": true,
                "inspiring": false
        }
    }]
}
```

Using plain JavaScript, how to pull all quotes from 1999? or all quotes with attribute inspiring = true?

Comment: And "best" is a subjective word. Best in terms of performance? Code clarity? Memory use? Conciseness?

Comment: This question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

"Best" can mean any number of things. **I** would probably do this:

```
 var obj = /* ...deserialize the JSON ...*/;
 var quotesSince1999 = obj.AllQuotes.filter(function(quote) {
     return quote.StatedYear >= 1999;
 });
```

That uses the `Array#filter` function from ES5, which can be shimmed on (the small number of) older browsers. It returns an array containing the entries for which the comparator function you give it returns a truthy value. The result in `quotesSince1999` is an array containing only the quotes where `StatedYear` is `>=` 1999.

Answer (score 0):

So , to get specific node object we will use the function above.

**Demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/nzLnofhz/

**Implementation:**

```js
var data = [{
  "AllQuotes": [{
    "Quote": "Life is Bad",
    "Attributes": {
      "StatedYear": 1999,
      "smart": true,
      "inspiring": false
    }
  }, {
    "Quote": "Life is Good",
    "Attributes": {
      "StatedYear": 1972,
      "smart": false,
      "inspiring": true
    }
  }, {
    "Quote": "Let's Party",
    "Attributes": {
      "StatedYear": 1999,
      "smart": false,
      "inspiring": true
    }
  }, {
    "Quote": "All is a Game",
    "Attributes": {
      "StatedYear": 1952,
      "smart": true,
      "inspiring": false
    }
  }]
}];
var getSpecificObjects = function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
      if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
        objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
      } else

      if (i == key && obj[i] == val || i == key && val == '') { //
        objects.push(obj);
      } else if (obj[i] == val && key == '') {
        //only add if the object is not already in the array
        if (objects.lastIndexOf(obj) == -1) {
          objects.push(obj);
        }
      }
    }
    return objects;
  }
  //First one  pull all quotes from 1999
var allQuotes1999 = getSpecificObjects(data, "StatedYear", "1999");
console.log(allQuotes1999);
//all quotes with attribute inspiring = true
var allQuotesInspiring = getSpecificObjects(data, "inspiring", true);
console.log(allQuotesInspiring);
```

Your result is two objects containing only the nodes with the specified values (*see your console after running the code):

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to search in Json By Either Value or Key Or Both :

```
function searchJson(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));    
        } else 
        if (i == key && obj[i] == val || i == key && val == '') { //
            objects.push(obj);
        } else if (obj[i] == val && key == ''){
            //only add if the object is not already in the array
            if (objects.lastIndexOf(obj) == -1){
                objects.push(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

You can use this function like this:
Assuming obj is your Json Object ,

```
getObjects(obj,"StatedYear","1999");
```

And It will return searched object , 
You can also use it like this to get all the values match to "1999" like this :

```
getObjects(obj,"","1999");
```

Or Like this which will return all object having "StatedYear" as a key

```
getObjects(obj,"StatedYear");
```